# Как подставлять список в цикл python?

Tags: python, selenium, for

Не могу понять как вставить список в цикл. Глупый вопрос, но я весь день уже убил, попробовал многое, но к успеху так и не пришел. Суть в том, что нужно подставлять номера телефонов в ссылку, и запускать через selenium. И вроде вопрос до абсурда прост, но я никак не могу прийти в чем именно я глуп.

```
nombe = ['7XXXXXXXXX','7XXXXXXXXXX', '7XXXXXXXXXX']
cl = nombe

cl.append()
print(nombe)


# lines = test.readlines()
# print(lines)

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
time.sleep(15)
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(5)



for driver in cl:
    driver.get(f'https://tarassenko.ru/wa.php?phone=' + cl)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p').send_keys('proverka_HZ')
    Keys.ENTER
```

Код ошибки:

```
   driver.get('https://tarassenko.ru/wa.php?phone=' + cl)AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get
```

Comment: У вас внутри цикла `driver` это строка `'7XXXXXXXXX'`, а у строк не бывает методов get или find_element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно догадался:

```
nombe = ['7XXXXXXXXX','7XXXXXXXXXX', '7XXXXXXXXXX']
print(nombe)

# lines = test.readlines()
# print(lines)

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
time.sleep(15)
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(5)

for num in numbe:
    driver.get(f'https://tarassenko.ru/wa.php?phone=' + num)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p').send_keys('proverka_HZ')
    Keys.ENTER
```